# How to convert the result of a command into a 2D array in PowerShell?

Tags: json, powershell

## Known

Consider the following command:

#### `ls -l`

```
-rwx------  123 ladiesman217  root    549 Apr 01 01:01 one.txt
-rwx------  123 ladiesman217  root    549 Apr 01 02:02 two.txt
-rwx------  123 ladiesman217  root    549 Apr 01 03:03 three.txt
```

When piped to `ConvertTo-Json`, it creates an array like so:

#### `ls -l | ConvertTo-Json`

```json
[
  "-rwx------  123 ladiesman217  root    549 Apr 01 01:01 one.txt",
  "-rwx------  123 ladiesman217  root    549 Apr 01 02:02 two.txt",
  "-rwx------  123 ladiesman217  root    549 Apr 01 03:03 three.txt"
]
```

## Objective

Is there a quick way to make it into a 2d array something like:

```json
[
  [
    "-rwx------",
    "123",
    "ladiesman217",
    "root",
    "549",
    "Apr",
    "01",
    "01:01",
    "one.txt"
  ],
  [
    "-rwx------",
    "123",
    "ladiesman217",
    "root",
    "549",
    "Apr",
    "01",
    "02:02",
    "two.txt"
  ],
  [
    "-rwx------",
    "123",
    "ladiesman217",
    "root",
    "549",
    "Apr",
    "01",
    "03:03",
    "three.txt"
  ]
]
```

In essence, it would be something like converting an `object` into an `array`.

How to convert the result of a command into a 2D array in PowerShell?

Comment: This worked for me but only if the files / folders don't have spaces `ls -l|select -skip 1|%{$_ -split '\s{1,}'|convertto-json}`. Note that I'm using `select -skip 1` because in pwsh in Linux the first line gives you a Total.

Comment: I'm gonna post an answer to show you how it looks for me and delete it after. I don't have any errors when running it.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I tried your example but it seems to have a *non-json* syntax like so:
`[...][...][...]`. But it is something (almost there)

Comment: Yeah, I know. You also will have a problem when you encounter a fiel / folder with spaces. It will be easier for you to convert `ls -l` to a PSCustomObject and then convert that object to JSON imo.

Answer (score 2):

To make a 2D array exactly like you've shown, you can do this.

```
   ls -l | Select-Object -Skip 1 | %{, -split $_ | ConvertTo-Json}
```

[image]

---

However to instead make usable objects with properties, I like this recipe.

- Switch statement
- Just enough regex
- A pinch of string manipulation
- Unary operator
- PSCustomObject

```
    $output = switch -Regex (ls -l){
        '(.+?)\s(\w{3}\s.+?:\d{1,})\s(.+?)$' {
            , -split $matches.1 | Foreach-Object {
                [PSCustomObject]@{
                    Permission = $_[0]
                    Links      = $_[1]
                    Owner      = $_[2]
                    Group      = $_[3]
                    Size       = $_[4]
                    Modified   = $matches.2
                    FileName   = $matches.3
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $output | Format-Table
```

Output
[image]

**TL;DR**

The switch statement is great for reading lines whether that's from a file, command output, etc. We only grab those lines that match the regex pattern.

**Regex explanation**

- `.+?` says to match any amount of any character, but as few as possible.
- `( )` puts anything that matches the pattern in the parenthesis in a capture group. By default will be numbered groups, can name them if you like.
- `\s` match a single space
- `\w{3}` match 3 word characters
- `:` match a literal colon
- `\d{1,}` match one or more numerical digits
- `$` the end of the line. (the match right before this must be at the end of the line)

So we capture the first 5 columns in `$matches.1`, the time stamp in `$matches.2`, and the rest of the text (which should be file/folder name) in `$matches.3`

From there we split `$matches.1` at the spaces by putting the split first. Normally when you split and send down the pipeline it will be one at a time.

```
-split "a b c" | %{"$_"}
```

[image]

By adding the comma to the front that turns it into an array and is sent down the pipeline as such.

```
, -split "a b c" | %{"$_"}
```

[image]

Then we just put each value in the correct spot. You can also turn into a JSON object.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With this you could convert the result of `ls -l` to a PS Object which then can be piped to `ConvertTo-Json` in case you need Json as result. Now I'm not very good with regex, this example will work only if the files / folders don't have white spaces. If someone can help with the correct regex to split it, that would be great:

```
$lsObject=ls -l|select -skip 1|%{
    $tmp=$_ -split '\s{1,}'
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Permission = $tmp[0]
        Links = $tmp[1]
        Owner = $tmp[2]
        Group = $tmp[3]
        Size = $tmp[4]
        LastModified = '{0} {1} {2}' -f $tmp[5],$tmp[6],$tmp[7]
        FileName = $tmp[8]
    }
}
```

Here is how the object looks:
[image]